# mocker won't mock requests session

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm tyring to mock the behavior of code that uses the library requests and uses requests. Session
However I can't make mocker to mock the Session.get() method:

```py
from mocker import Mocker, ANY
mocker = Mocker()
obj = mocker.proxy("requests.Session") #replace didn't work either
obj.get("anyurl")
mocker.result("mocksessionget")
mocker.replay()
import requests
s = requests.Session()
x = s.get("anyurl")
```

session.get is not mocked and this code throws:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'anyurl'
```

Comment: You could install a testing adapter instead; see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-testadapter for a package that gives you a ready-made one.

Comment: I'll consider that, but mocker should do the work.

Comment: it seems that mocker.replace("requests.Session.get") works but it makes test very complicated.

Comment: how you made it work with that replace? can you build a small answer please? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's impossible to mock requests.Session directly.

To the benefit of others here is how I managed to solve this:

```
requests_mock = mocker.replace("requests")
session_mock = mocker.mock()
requests_mock.Session()
mocker.result(session_mock)
```

You may have to add few calls to mocker to make it happy with it's ref counting.